# extracting multiple line of a text file into a new text file

Tags: file, batch-file, text

is that possible to make a batch file for my problem ?

I need to extract text file that contents of multiple line 
here is the scenario of the batch file.

I have  a txt file with file name 13051710_140211094000.txt

and the content of that file is :

```
14/02/11 09:20:00; 982.8; 15; 17; 18;
14/02/11 09:30:00; 983.0; 16; 18; 21; 1; 100; 158; 54; 131; 174; 
14/02/11 09:40:00; 983.1; 20; 21; 22; 0; 100; 127; 60; 
14/02/11 09:50:00; 983.1; 19; 20; 22; 0; 100; 149; 86; 
14/02/11 10:00:00; 983.2; 19; 20; 21; 0; 100; 151;
```

I need to extract each line to a new txt file . 
The new text file should be take the time stamp from each line and convert it to file name .

The new text file should be like this

MYDATA_140211092000.txt

and the content of that file is :

```
14/02/11 09:20:00; 982.8; 15; 17; 18;
```

And should be create another file, from next line of master content , with that rule .

Thanks and regards

Comment: Is `MYDATA` literally "MYDATA" or is that part of the extracted line?

Comment: MYDATA is literally MYDATA , not part of data to be extracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /L %%t IN (0,1,9) DO FOR %%u IN (%%t*_*.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN (%%u) DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-6delims=/:; " %%a IN ("%%q") DO (
  >>MYDATA_%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f.txt ECHO(%%q
  )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

As a windows `.cmd` batch script - you haven't made that explicit.

(revised version, assuming target files are named in format `n*_*.txt` with `n` numeric.)

Comment: This batch script works for me , thanks for your help .
But there is something i forgot to explain ,what if  i have more than one file of text file with that type , for example i have three  txt file in same folder , 
13051710_140211094000.txt
13051710_140211095000.txt
13051710_140211096000.txt

Comment: Edited version works for me , great ! and  many thanks. Another Case , what if i mentioned , that i want character 13051710 , to be my master key to identify the file . Actualy that is a serial number of my devices.
It may usefull if i had another file from another device in same folder , such as 12051711_timestamp, as you can see my sample file is following by time stamp after _ character.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-6,* delims=/:; " %%a in ("13051710_140211094000.txt") do (
    >>"MYDATA_%%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f.txt" echo(%%a/%%b/%%c %%d:%%e:%%f; %%g
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
datestamp=$(echo $line | cut -f 1 -d " ");
day=$(echo $datestamp |cut -f 1 -d "/")
month=$(echo $datestamp |cut -f 2 -d "/")
year=$(echo $datestamp |cut -f 3 -d "/")

timestamp=$(echo $line | cut -f 2 -d " " | cut -f 1 -d ";")
hour=$(echo $timestamp |cut -f 1 -d ":")
min=$(echo $timestamp |cut -f 2 -d ":")
sec=$(echo $timestamp |cut -f 3 -d ":")

echo $line > MYDATA_$day$month$year$hour$min$sec.txt
done < file.txt
```

change file.txt in the last line to your master filename

Comment: i think he needs a batch and not a bash file :)